# Bash script outputting MySQL mediumtext one word per line

Tags: mysql, bash, echo

I am writing a BASH script to output the contents of mediumtext fields from a MySQL database. It works, but my problem is every word in the mediumtext field are echoed on a separate line.

```
for i in $( mysql -u $user -p$password my_db -ss -e "SELECT myticket_data.subject FROM myticket_data INNER JOIN myticket ON myticket_data.ticket_id = myticket.ticket_id WHERE myticket.status = 'open';" ); do
echo $i
done
```

Instead of:

> I like to move it move it

I get:

> I
>
> like
>
> to
>
> move
>
> it
>
> move
>
> it

Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found I needed to properly set the new line character by adding this before my loop:

```
 IFS='
 '
```

[Found the answer here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/looping-over-mysql-query-results-in-bash-832351/)